# Auth0 login redirect to page keeps on loading when using Firefox as browser

Tags: authentication, firefox, redirect, loading, auth0

I use an Auth0 login that handles the login for my platform after logging in it redirects you to the platform. With chrome, this works perfectly but in Firefox it keeps reloading the redirect page. I used the standard auth0 code to implement the logic into my page. I'm not sure what is going wrong and even where to start looking for a solution? Does anyone ever experienced the same bug and can help me fix the issue and also explain what is going wrong?

auth.ts file :

```
export class AuthService {
  // Create an observable of Auth0 instance of client
  auth0Client$ = (from(
    createAuth0Client({
      domain: authConfig.domain,
      client_id: authConfig.clientId,
      redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}`,
      audience: authConfig.audience,
    })
  ) as Observable<Auth0Client>).pipe(
    shareReplay(1), // Every subscription receives the same shared value
    catchError(err => throwError(err))
  );

  // Manage Acces Token
  // Observable method to retrieve access token and make it available for use in application
  getTokenSilently$(options?): Observable<string> {
    return this.auth0Client$.pipe(
      concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.getTokenSilently(options)))
    );
  }

  // Define observables for SDK methods that return promises by default
  // For each Auth0 SDK method, first ensure the client instance is ready
  // concatMap: Using the client instance, call SDK method; SDK returns a promise
  // from: Convert that resulting promise into an observable
  isAuthenticated$ = this.auth0Client$.pipe(
    concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.isAuthenticated())),
    tap(res => (this.loggedIn = res))
  );
  handleRedirectCallback$ = this.auth0Client$.pipe(
    concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.handleRedirectCallback()))
  );
  // Create subject and public observable of user profile data
  private userProfileSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  userProfile$ = this.userProfileSubject$.asObservable();
  // Create a local property for login status
  loggedIn: boolean = null;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    // On initial load, check authentication state with authorization server
    // Set up local auth streams if user is already authenticated
    this.localAuthSetup();
    // Handle redirect from Auth0 login
    this.handleAuthCallback();
  }

  // When calling, options can be passed if desired
  // https://auth0.github.io/auth0-spa-js/classes/auth0client.html#getuser
  getUser$(options?): Observable<any> {
    return this.auth0Client$.pipe(
      concatMap((client: Auth0Client) => from(client.getUser(options))),
      tap(user => this.userProfileSubject$.next(user))
    );
  }

  private localAuthSetup() {
    // This should only be called on app initialization
    // Set up local authentication streams
    const checkAuth$ = this.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
      concatMap((loggedIn: boolean) => {
        if (loggedIn) {
          // If authenticated, get user and set in app
          // NOTE: you could pass options here if needed
          return this.getUser$();
        }
        // If not authenticated, return stream that emits 'false'
        return of(loggedIn);
      })
    );
    checkAuth$.subscribe();
  }

  login(redirectPath: string = '/') {
    // A desired redirect path can be passed to login method
    // (e.g., from a route guard)
    // Ensure Auth0 client instance exists
    this.auth0Client$.subscribe((client: Auth0Client) => {
      // Call method to log in
      client.loginWithRedirect({
        redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}`,
        appState: { target: redirectPath },
      });
    });
  }



  private handleAuthCallback() {
    // Call when app reloads after user logs in with Auth0
    const params = window.location.search;
    if (params.includes('code=') && params.includes('state=')) {
      let targetRoute: string; // Path to redirect to after login processsed
      const authComplete$ = this.handleRedirectCallback$.pipe(
        // Have client, now call method to handle auth callback redirect
        tap(cbRes => {
          // Get and set target redirect route from callback results
          targetRoute = cbRes.appState && cbRes.appState.target ? cbRes.appState.target : '/';
        }),
        concatMap(() => {
          // Redirect callback complete; get user and login status
          return combineLatest([this.getUser$(), this.isAuthenticated$]);
        })
      );
      // Subscribe to authentication completion observable
      // Response will be an array of user and login status
      authComplete$.subscribe(([user, loggedIn]) => {
        // Redirect to target route after callback processing
        this.router.navigate([targetRoute]);
      });
    }
  }

  logout() {
    // Ensure Auth0 client instance exists
    this.auth0Client$.subscribe((client: Auth0Client) => {
      // Call method to log out
      client.logout({
        client_id: authConfig.clientId,
        returnTo: window.location.origin,
      });
    });
  }
}
```

auth-guard.ts

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
      tap(loggedIn => {
        if (!loggedIn) {
          this.auth.login(state.url);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and found that it was because my browser was blocking third party cookies.

So my app was running on my own domain (or on localhost in dev mode), but I was using an auth0.com subdomain to log in with Auth0 and the browser was blocking cookies from auth0.com, which sent the auth0 JS in my app into an infinite loop of trying to check the logged in status, failing, refreshing the page, trying to check the logged in status, failing, refreshing the page, and so on.

It could be your browser's cookie settings or an ad blocking or privacy extension.